# Application LMS function to a wave file on hard disk

Tags: python, filter, fft, noise, wave

I have found [this function online](https://github.com/awesomebytes/parametric_modeling/blob/master/src/by_hand_code/lms.py) and I want use it with a wave file saved on my hard disk. 
Could you help me figure out how to do it? What parameters should be used as  inputs to the function and how do I obtain them from wave files? through FFT?

```
def lms(x, d, p, mu, w0=None):
""" Finds the LMS adaptive filter w based on the inputs

Adapted from the Hayes MATLAB code.

Inputs:
    x: input data to the filter, Nx1 vector
    d: desired output signal, Nx1 vector
    p: filter order
    mu: step size, scalar or Nx1 vector
    w0: initial guess (optional)

Outputs:
    w: filter coefficient matrix: w[n,p] where 
        n is the time index and 
        p is the filter tap index
    e: error sequence e(n): Nx1 vector

"""
# Initialize
N = len(x)
X = convm.convm(x, p)
if not w0:
    w0 = np.zeros(p)
# Promote mu to be a vector if it's not already
if not isinstance(mu, np.ndarray):
    mu = np.ones(N) * mu
w = np.zeros((N,p))
e = np.zeros(N)
w[0,:] = w0

# Run the filter
for n in xrange(N-1):
    y = np.dot(w[n,:], X[n,:])
    e[n] = d[n] - y
    w[n+1,:] = w[n,:] + mu[n] * e[n] * X[n,:].conj()

return w, e
```

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve and why do you think the LMS algorithm will help you achieve that goal? If you have an audio file that has been altered in some way by some filter or channel, then you can use the altered audio together with the original audio to estimate the filter coeffients of the filter that altered the audio.

Comment: I wanted to apply the filter LMS only for university research that I'm doing. It has only one use of some tests I need to do